# What kind of adhesive should be used to install marble tile?

Tags: flooring, marble

Looking to have large 24x24 Marble tiles put around and under a new cast iron pedestal tub.  What adhesive should the contractor use? Is there a problem putting these under the very heavy tub?

Comment: What are the tiles going on? Plywood? Concrete?

Comment: Thinset mortar is almost always used for floor tile. It's important to use a color or type that won't bleed through your natural stone and leave stains. (For white tile, use white mortar.) The specific type depends on the substrate.

Answer (score 2):

Since it’s going to be in a “damp” area I would use thinset mortar. With tiles that large a large notch trowel will be needed.

Comment: The disconcerting part is that large tiles require skill. Asking what adhesive to use is pretty basic. If this needs to be asked, what are the chances the tiles end up flat enough and stable enough to avoid future issues?